# Null row value if data same in column for selected column postgresql sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I have a table like this:

| cms_code | product |
| --- | --- |
| 55381XA384 | MS |
| 55381XA384 | MS |
| 55381XA384 | HSD |
| 55381XA384 | HSD |
| 55381XA382 | HSD |
| 55381XA382 | XP |
| 55381XA382 | MS |
| 55381XA382 | HSD |
| 55381XA382 | HSD |

Now, I need a result like this:

| cms_code | product |
| --- | --- |
| 55381XA384 | MS |
| NULL | MS |
| NULL | HSD |
| NULL | HSD |
| 55381XA382 | HSD |
| NULL | XP |
| NULL | MS |
| NULL | HSD |
| NULL | HSD |

Comment: Why have you tagged your question with MySQL and Microsoft SQL Server if you are using PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 0):

you can use window functions to number the rows & set subsequent values to `null`, keeping the `cms_code` only for row number 1.

```sql
select 
  case 
    when row_number() over (partition by cms_code) = 1 then cms_code 
    else null 
  end cms_code
, product_code
from my_table
order by cms_code
```

Comment: @KaranChaudhari . . . No, it is not "working perfectly".  It may appear to work but without a stable `order by` in the outer query, the result set has no guaranteed ordering.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, would `row_number() over (partition by cms_code order by cms_code)` produce row numberings that are more stable than `row_number() over (partition by cms_code)`, and why

Comment: @HaleemurAli . . . No.  Just some databases (and the standard) require the `order by`, so I usually just include it.

Answer (score 0):

Your results depend on the ordering of the rows.  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets, so you cannot do what you want with the data you have.

Assuming you have a column that specifies the ordering, you *could* do:

```
select (case when row_number() over (partition by cms_code order by <ordering col< = 1
             then cms_code
        end) as cms_code, product_code
from t
order by cms_code, <ordering col>;
```

Without an ordering column, you can also do:

```
with cte as (
      select t.*, row_number() over (partition by cms_code order by cms_code) as seqnum
      from t
     )
select (case when seqnum = 1 then cms_code end) as cms_code,
       product_code
from t
order by cms_code, seqnum;
```

In both cases, you need the `order by` in the outer query to guarantee that the result set is ordered so the "first" row has the `cms_code`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want null for all the values of cms_code which is same after the first value. Correct me if I'm wrong Below query can be used for the same:

```
SELECT 
  CASE
    WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY cms_code order by product) = 1 
    THEN NULL 
    ELSE cms_code 
  END AS cms_code,product 
FROM table;
```